As / While +-ing verb
Consider the following two sentences:
"While eating food, I dropped sauce on my pants."
"As eating food, I dropped sauce on my pants."
Considering that both 'while' and 'as' are conjunctions, what is the specific reason why 'as' cannot begin a sentence but 'while' can?
Thank you~

2nd one doesn't make much sense to me. "As I ate my food, I dropped sauce on my pants" sounds ok to me though

While can be followed by an -ing form of a verb when talking about two actions taking place at the same time ("while eating food); as cannot. Both can also be followed by a finite clause ("as/while I was eating food"). This is just a quirk of English grammar.
Cambridge's grammar guide explains that you can use while (or when) without a subject to mean at the time, but you can't use as: "while there, ..." or "while in France, ...", or as in the question, "while cooking, ...".
However it gets complicated because of the different uses and meanings of both words. You can use "as" in a similar construction, but with a different meaning: "as in France" means "in the same way as is done in France". And "while" can also be used to mean although e.g. "while respected, he is not liked" (from M-W); you could also do this with -ing forms e.g. "while smelling nice, it tastes horrible", although this is probably commoner in writing than speech, and you'd probably say "while he's respected" or "while it smells nice" in speech.
It's not always clear which meaning of while or as is intended, and you may have to think for a while to tell; you can consult a dictionary for the possibilities.

Yes, while and as can be synonyms, but as can have other meanings.

While I was eating my lunch, I dropped spaghetti sauce on my pants.

The 'I was' can be omitted because the meaning is perfectly clear without it.
We can say as I was eating, but it doesn't sound right to say as eating my lunch. As at the beginning of a sentence could mean because or in the capacity of ('As your legal advisor, I would suggest...')
